# JavaScript / Node.js event loop tick ids

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am wondering if there is some neat way of knowing if a function is called in the current tick (the tick in which the function was declared), or the next tick (or some future tick) of the Node.js event loop

for example:

```
function foo(cb){

  // we can fire callback synchronously
  cb();

  // or we can fire callback asynchronously
  process.nextTick(cb);

}
```

say will call foo like so:

```
function outer(){

   const currentTickId = process.currentTickId;

  function bar(){          //bar gets created everytime outer is called..

    if(process.currentTickId === currentTickId){
       //do something
    }
    else{

     // do something else
    }


  }

  // foo is always called in the same tick that bar was
  // declared, but bar might not be called until the next tick

  foo(bar);  


}
```

most applications won't need something like this, but I am writing a library and it would be useful to have this functionality, if it's possible!  note that `process.currentTickId` is made up by me for this example

Comment: I guess it's "possible" - https://www.npmjs.com/package/tick-id

Comment: note that normally it's best practice to always fire callbacks asynchronously, but this is just an illustrative example

Comment: FYI the state of not being able to know if a function call is synchronous or asynchronous is/was known in the JS community as **Zalgo** - this usage predates "zalgo text" by at least 1 1/2 years. It's considered an anti-pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've already discovered [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args).

You could use this to rig up a system to achieve "`process.currentTickId`" as the code in your question indicates you need:

```
process.currentTickId = 0;

const onTick = () => {
    process.currentTickId++;
    process.nextTick(onTick);
};

process.nextTick(onTick);
```

Comment: ahh what youre missing is that this is for a library that will be used by devs. I want them to be able to call an API synchronously, but warn or throw errors if they call the API in nextTick, so I simply don't have control over when they use sync or async code, it's just not my code its theirs.

Comment: A little warning about this code, when you push onTick to the next tick queue from inside of onTick which is firing from the next tick queue, you basically block the event loop and it never exhausts the nextTick queue.  Other parts of the event loop will never fire, including timeouts, immediates, promises, I/O events, etc.

Comment: @AdamLockhart have you tried this code? Doubt that's true - node.js has different categories of async callbacks/tasks to process - certain things always run before nextTick calls and after nextTick calls for each cycle of the event loop. In other words, every time the event loop processes its tasks - it always will look at other things to process before processing nextTick requests.

Comment: @Emmett I am hoping that node.js core can add an id for us, so we don't have to add a runtime listener

Comment: Actually Adam is right. I've encountered this 3 years ago. I was surprised why my network requests didn't work and I discovered that calling `process.nextTick` recursively means the "certain things that always run after nextTick calls" never execute (and network I/O happens to be one of them). I solved it by replacing `nextTick` with `setTimeout(.., 0)`. Essentially you never enter the state of "after nextTick call" and never exit the current event loop

Comment: Regarding the recursion issue: How come we don't simply do this using `setImmediate` (instead of `nextTick`)? Wouldn't that give us a new id per tick without this problem?

Comment: Idea is good but it will block event loop. It will recursively queue itself blocking all pending tasks to run.

Answer (score 2):

NPM lib:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-loop-ticks

Improved answer basing on @Emmett post:

```js
let _tick = 0;
const onTick = () => {
  _tick++;
  setImmediate(() => process.nextTick(onTick)).unref();
};
process.nextTick(onTick);
```